# How to insert a registry that is an object containing another object, to a database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm getting problems inserting registries on a table that uses external keys. To define the tables, I use classes to store personal information (name, age, etc). Now, one of my tables uses a class that also contains another class (which is the original table from where the external key comes from). For example:

```
//Variables declared here
private long codeDestiny;
private String location;
private TypeDestiny typeDestiny; /*Another class I created which has only the primary key (long) and a String that works as a description for the type*/

//One of two constructors
public Destino(TypeDestiny typeDestiny, String location) {
     this.typeDestiny= typeDestiny;
     this.location = location;
}

//The other constructor
public Destino(long codeDestiny, TypeDestiny typeDestiny, String location) {
    this.codDestino = codeDestiny;
    this.typeDestiny = typeDestiny;
    this.location = location;
}

//Getters
public long getCodeDestiny() {
    return codeDestiny;
}

public TypeDestiny getTypeDestiny() {
    return typeDestiny;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
```

Now, my problem is that I can create a method that is used to insert registries using the following piece of code but I can't create a method to get all the registries from the same table. Can anybody tell me what to do?

```
// Code for inserting registries into the table
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DESTINY_COLUMN_COD, destiny.getCodeDestiny());
values.put(TYPEDESTINY_COLUMN_TYPE, destiny.getTypeDestiny().getTypeDestiny());
values.put(DESTINY_COLUMN_LOCALIDADE, destiny.getLocalidade());

long itemId = db.insert(DESTINY_TABLE_NAME, null, values);

db.close();

// Code for selecting all the registries
List<Destiny> destinies = new ArrayList<>();
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

String query = "SELECT * FROM " +
DESTINY_TABLE_NAME + ", " + TYPEDESTINY_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DESTINY_TABLE_NAME + "." + TYPEDESTINY_COLUMN_TYPE + " = " +
TYPEDESTINY_TABLE_NAME + "." + TYPEDESTINY_COLUMN_TYPE ;

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
       long codeDestiny = cursor.getLong(0);
       TypeDestiny codTypeDestiny = cursor.;
       String location = cursor.getString(2);

       Destiny destiny = new Destiny(codeDestiny, codeTypeDestiny, location);
       destinies.add(destiny);
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

cursor.close();
db.close();
```